# Jump between words with varying separators in vim

Tags: vim

I have a few different keys to jump between words, depending on what separators I want to include:

```
" Use _ as a word separator when moving between words with q and t
noremap q :set iskeyword-=_<CR>b:set iskeyword+=_<CR>
noremap t :set iskeyword-=_<CR>w:set iskeyword+=_<CR>
```

This, however, doesn't work with multi-key commands like `dq`, `dt`, `cq`, or `ct`. Can I create a version of these keys which will work with multi-key commands like this?

Bear in mind I don't want to lose the functionality of jumping between words normally (e.g. with `w`, `e`, `b`), I just want to add keys with different functionality.

Thanks!

Comment: I can understand using `q` for an operator pending mode mapping, however using `t` I feel would be a great loss. Vim's `t` and `f` commands are just too useful to be mapped over carelessly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Operator Pending Mapping](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#omap-info):

```
:onoremap t :<c-u>normal t<cr>
:onoremap q :<c-u>normal q<cr>
```

<strike>Remember to declare them after your normal mapping, because they are based in those ones.</strike>

Comment: Documentation and example at [`:h omap-info`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#omap-info).

Comment: @glts: Thank you. I've added the link o the answer.

Comment: The order is irrelevant, as the dependency is during execution, not definition.